# Push the gitignore file alone at the begin

Tags: java, git, github, netbeans, gitignore

We are five students in a team and  we must work in the same project using git.
What i did is:

1. create an empty project
2. add gitignore file

   The gitignore file
   contains:

   ```
   *.class
   nbproject/private/
   build/
   nbbuild/
   dist/
   nbdist/
   nbactions.xml
   nb-configuration.xml
   ```
3. git init
4. git add .
5. git commit -m "Initial commit"
6. set up the remote and push

But we have a conflict in nbproject/private/private.properties file.
This file contains:

```
user.properties.file=C:\\Users\\Houssem\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\8.2\\build.properties
user.properties.file=C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\8.2\\build.properties
```

One of us he had cloned the repository and he can't add any java class in his local project.

Comment: By "gitignore file", you meant `.gitignore`, right? That is, the filename starts with a dot. Btw, is the output of this command empty? -> `git ls-files | grep nbproject/private/`

Comment: no it is not empty there is one line.nbproject/private/private.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confirmed in a comment that the output of `git ls-files | grep nbproject/private/` contains `line.nbproject/private/private.properties`.
That means the file `line.nbproject/private/private.properties` is part of the repository.
You need to remove the file with `git rm line.nbproject/private/private.properties`,
and then commit the changes.
After that none of your collaborators should get any conflicts on this file.

Having `nbproject/private/` in the `.gitignore` file should normally prevent `line.nbproject/private/private.properties` from getting added to the repository.
But it's possible that the file was added to the repository before `.gitignore` was created,
or that one of the collaborators force-added it (`git add -f ...`).

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you might want to set up NetBeans to keep the project workspace (I believe this is called "Project" in NetBeans) outside of the actual repository and code, since this contains absolute references and (I'm assuming here) personal preferences.

I have no experience with NetBeans, but in Eclipse this works just fine.

Keeping the workspace files separate should also allow each developer to use an editor of his or her choice instead of being locked to one.